# iOS displaying remote images with dynamic dimension (in URL) using device scale

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am using following method to display a remote image of 100pt x 100pt (for example), I first detect iOS device scale and generate a dynamic URL, as following:

```
private func getImageURL() -> String {
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
    if (!screen.respondsToSelector(Selector("scale"))) {
        return "http://cdn.domain.by/100x100/image.jpg"
    }
    if (screen.scale > 2) {
        return "http://cdn.domain.by/300x300/image.jpg" // iPhone 6+
    }

    return "http://cdn.domain.by/200x200/image.jpg"
}
```

Above approach works fine, but since latest Swift update, I get following warning message:

> Replace Selector("scale") with #selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale)

**Question 1**: Is it safe to remove these lines:

```
    if (!screen.respondsToSelector(Selector("scale"))) {
        return "http://cdn.domain.by/100x100/image.jpg"
    }
```

**Question 2**: Should I detect device scale? or even theres a better approach for generating such URL

Comment: You don't need to check if `mainScreen()` responds to `#selector(scale)`. `scale` was added in iOS 4.0. I think, it's safe to assume that your deployment target is well pass that. If you are targeting iOS 8.0 and up, you might consider using `traitCollection.displayScale`.

Comment: @beyowulf, understood, thanks